# How to put data from one column in the empty row of another column - Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How do I put data from COL2 in the empty rows of COL1? (empty rows are represented by --)

```
COL1   COL2
6       --                
5.5     --                 
--      4.5
1.4     --                 
3.75    --                 
7       --                 
--      5
7.5     --                 
2.25    --                 
1.25    --                 
--      5
4.5     --                 
3       --                 
1.67    --                 
--      7
```

Comment: Do you mean when you query, or to actually update the table?

Comment: Make sure to provide sample *output* (and usage cues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try :

```
   UPDATE table
SET col1 = CASE WHEN col1 ='--' THEN col2 
                 ELSE col1 END,
    col2 = CASE WHEN col2='--' THEN col1
                  ELSE col2 END
WHERE col2='--'
  OR col1 ='--';
```

<kbd>[fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7eb0c/2)</kbd>

Comment: sorry OP never said he wants to identical columns

Comment: set `col2=col1 where col1='' makes col1,col2 identical  ? `

Comment: yes i just want to transfer the data in COL2 into the corresponding empty space (yes NUll is the empty cells ) in COL1

Answer (score 0):

```
Update tableName set COL1 = COL2 where COL1 = ''
```

or

```
Update tableName set COL1 = COL2 where isnull(COL1 , '') = ''
```

Comment: check this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a2a79/2

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi .. i co not want to expain you but i know you have given downvote .. can u please expain why u downvoted the answer ??

Comment: WTF , can u please give me the link where it says `isnull(col1,'') ='' ` will not work ??? I have been using it forever and u r saying it will no work

Comment: @dhaval Do not attempt to guess who has voted for you. You will almost always be wrong. Like now...

Comment: @AndrewBarber .. You can see my previous downvote .. i never tried to guess it but this time i am quiet sure  about this .. it is much better to let the wrong answer to be upvoted then try to make a point

Comment: -**I**- am the down voter... because you are just making a wild stab in the dark guess as to what this question even is.

Comment: @Dhaval : pls explain this `isnull(col1,'') ='' ` [seeing hereeeeeee](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a2a79/2)  and [my answer](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a2a79/4) and i didnt downvote you..i never wish my rep go down by -1